# Finding the smallest distance from any vertex to the border of the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, distance, breadth-first-search, memoization

So I have triangular mesh approximating a surface.

It's like a graph with the following properties:

- The vertices on the graph border are trivially identifiable. (Number of neighbor vertices > number of containing triangles)
- You can trivially calculate the distance between any two vertices. (Euclidean distance)
- For any vertex *v*, any vertex that is not a neighbor of *v* must have a greater distance to *v* than at least one of *v*'s neighbors. In other words, no non-neighbor vertices may appear within *v*'s neighborhood ring.

For each vertex *v*, I want to calculate the smallest distance from v to any border vertex.

I can do this by brute force, build a list of all border vertices, compare *v*'s distance to each, and keep the minimum. But this is inefficient.

I believe the most efficient way for each single vertex *v* is to do have a priority queue where the top element is the closest to *v*. The queue is initialized with *v*'s neighbors. While the top of the queue is not a border vertex, pop the top and push all the neighbors of the popped vertex.

Let's say vertex *v* has 6 neighbors, and I calculate the minimum border distance for each of the 6, and I recorded the exact border vertex that gave the minimum for the 6 neighbors. I know that one of these must also give *v*'s minimum border value. I can't really prove this, but I think it's intuitive. If *v*'s surrounded by it's neighbors, the closest border vertex to *v* must also be the closest border vertex to one of its neighbors.

I want to know if there is a way to use this knowledge to efficiently computing the minimum for each point in the graph. More efficient than a breadth first search from each vertex.

Answer (score 0):

If you do breadth-first search until you find a border vertex, this does not guarantee that this is the closest border vertex.  To see this, note that for any triangulated planar graph in 2-d, you could add a very small distinct z-coordinate to each vertex, and define a 3-d surface whose natural simplest good approximating triangular mesh (giving a perfect approximation) is simply the mesh corresponding to the original planar graph.  So it suffices to give an example of a triangulated planar graph where there are vertices v whose closest border vertex in terms of minimum #edges on a path connecting v to the border vertex is not the closest border vertex in terms of euclidean distance.  Here's an example of such a planar graph.

First draw a right triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,1).  Then choose a large number of vertices along the edge from (1,0) to (0,1), such that the vertices break up the edge into equal sized segments.  Connect all these vertices to (0,0).  Then, for all the vertices you added, for each pair of neighboring vertices draw an equilateral triangle that uses the two vertices as two of the equilateral triangle vertices.  Connect all the "tops" of the equilateral triangles with a straight line.  Now you should have a region that looks like the first level of a house of cards.  Similarly add the second level of the house of cards on top of the first.  This is the graph, and it satisfies your properties.  Now note, for all of the vertices you added along the edge from (1,0) to (0,1), they have (0,0) as a neighbor and this is a border vertex.  However,  the closest border vertex in terms of euclidean distance will be one of the border vertices along the perimeter of your 2-level house of cards, which will be almost always be 2 edges away.  A breadth first search from one of these interior vertices would return (0,0) as the closest border vertex, which is incorrect.  I think this example is just a glimpse of how complicated things can get, such that your assumptions are still satisfied.  The fastest algorithm may indeed be to just enumerate all border vertices, and then for each vertex test all border vertices to find the closest.  If you have a nice "fat" mesh with most of the vertices not being border vertices, at least the number of border vertices will be much smaller than the total number of vertices, so the complexity is at least reduced some from the worst-case O(N^2) if you have N vertices.

Comment: You're assuming I'm applying breadth first search by graph distance instead of Euclidean distance. If I have a priority queue with smallest Euclidean distance on top, then the first border to be popped out would still be the vertex on the house of cards, because the (0,0) vertex would keep getting pushed down by the newly pushed, closer vertices. The algorithm would start with a priority queue, ordered by Euclidean distance, of the neighbor vertices of *v*, and while the top of the queue isn't a border vertex, pop off the top, and push on all the neighbors of the popped vertex.

Comment: i've never heard something like that called breadth first search -- the actual computational path to reach the border vertex might actually be the same as depth-first search (where the closest neighbor is traversed first).  i'd recommend editing your post

Comment: Breadth first search is probably the wrong name for it. But I know it's definitely not depth first search (the opposite of what you have in parentheses). I'll edit the post.